# I'm trying to find a prime number at this section

Tags: c++

The user is asked to put a number from 1 to a and then if the user puts 1 for the integer c. I supposed to find every prime number between 1 and a. This compiles fine but it prints every number between 1 and a.

```
if (c == 0) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
}
else {
    for (int i = 2; i <= a; i++) {
        for (int c = 1; c <= a; c++) {
            if (i % c == 0) {
                cout << i << " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `c` for?

Comment: I have other sections .. this is section c. Basically if the  user inputs the number 1 instead of 0 it should print out all the prime numbers between 1 and a

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We cannot know what your code is actually doing without seeing the missing parts. By adding something one could make this snippet bascially print anything

Comment: @EliasIoannou Post a [mcve] that reproduces your problem as required here please. Also that doesn't look like an algorithm to find prime numbers for me.

Comment: You're printing all the divisors of all the numbers from 2 to `a`. Start with reviewing what a prime number is. Then write some code that determines whether a single number is prime. Then add a loop that finds all of them.

Comment: you have two different `c`s in your code, is this intentional?

Comment: @EliasIoannou In your code, It is printing every factor of number in for loop. Prime numbers are those which have only two factors 1 and itself. Your code is printing each factor of i(in the for loop). I have sample code for finding prime numbers between 1 to a. Link: https://pastebin.com/nd4a9vps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it prints every number between 1 and a.

In

> ```
> for (int i = 2; i <= a; i++) {
>    for (int c = 1; c <= a; c++) {
>        if (i % c == 0) {
>            cout << i << " ";
>        }
>    }
> }
> ```

the first value of *c* is 1 and for all non null number `i % 1` is 0 so you print at least one time all numbers from 2 up to a

in the second loop *c* will also value *i* so you do `i % i` and of course the modulo is 0 again and you print at least a second time all numbers from 2 up to a

of course there are other cases where the modulo can be 0

> The user is asked to put a number from 1 to a and then if the user puts 1 for the integer c

I do not understand that sentence, something is wrong or missing

> I supposed to find every prime number between 1 and a

this is not what you do, you have to check *all* modulo are *not* 0 except with 1 and the number itself

Can be (lazy way) :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "enter max number" << std::endl;

  int a;

  if (!(std::cin >> a) || (a < 1)) // even we know 1 is not a prime number
    std::cerr << "invalid number" << std::endl;
  else {
    for (int i = 2; i <= a; ++i) {
      int c;

      for (c = i/2; c >= 2; --c) {
        if (i % c == 0)
          break;
      }
      if (c == 1)
        // prime 
        std::cout << i << " is a prime number" << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra m.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter max number
25
2 is a prime number
3 is a prime number
5 is a prime number
7 is a prime number
11 is a prime number
13 is a prime number
17 is a prime number
19 is a prime number
23 is a prime number
```